# Shell scripts triggered via ssh can't connect after 3 times

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I am running python server script in one of the linux machie via ssh. Server runs and active in port 12321. When client connects from another server, it works well for 3 times. When tries to connect for 4th time, it doesn't succeed.

command:

```
ssh $USER@$ipadress "bash -s" < scripts/test_execution_scripts/ssh_remote_tools.sh "$2" "$3" &
```

where ssh_remote_tools.sh has the shell commands that launch python server script

Note : Everything works well when python server is launched manually in that server. But when launched via ssh its not connecting after 4th attempt.

I tried changing the clientalivecountmax, clientaliveinterval, serveralivecountmax, serveraliveinterval in /etc/ssh/sshd_config & /etc/ssh/ssh_config files and restarted the ssh serveices. But that doesn't helps.

Comment: This not works for server script which uses the USB in the server machine.

Comment: SSH server configuration belongs at [unix.se], not here. If you have a question that _is_ on-topic here, it should be asked with a [mre] -- sufficient details to let us reproduce the problem ourselves and identify for a fact that it _is_ the same problem, not just similar symptoms. (Using `-v` to increase the log verbosity helps with that; if the connection is blocked at the TCP level vs the authentication level those are very different problems; you aren't giving us the specific error message you get at all, so we have nowhere to start but guesswork).

Comment: we can't run your code, and we can't reproduce your problem. We can't even see your code in script. And we can't read in your mind. So we have no idea what can be the problem.